# Make the text editable after press the button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

Is anyone know how to make the text editable after I press the button? I want it to be editable only when the user clicks the button. Below is the result that I needed.

[image]

If I want to edit the text "Festive Leave", then I need to click the edit button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this should do what you want.

```
TextEditingController _controller =
      TextEditingController(text: "Festive Leave");
  bool _isEnable = false;
//These are initialize at the top


Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  enabled: _isEnable,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isEnable = true;
                    });
                  })
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: That is how you initialize text field but I'll provide some more code below that will have a slightly different effect but doesn't use controller and you can pick what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100,
                child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Festive Leave",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              enabled: _isEnable,
            ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isEnable = true;
                    });
                  })
            ],
          ),
```

your choice this one the text will go away as soon as the user starts to type though

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot man,this helped me a lot, you are amazing!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
class SampleDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleDemoState createState() => _SampleDemoState();
}

class _SampleDemoState extends State<SampleDemo> {
  String title = "MyTitle";
  bool isEditable=false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      Expanded(
          child: !isEditable
              ? Text(title)
              : TextFormField(
                  initialValue: title,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                    setState(() => {isEditable = false, title = value});
                  })),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() => {
                isEditable = true,
              });
        },
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```